# I can't read .txt files from the raw folder

Tags: android, io

I am trying to learn how basic operations work in android apps. I have a .txt file in row folder  and I can't read anything. Because when I execute the code (although I don't get any logcat errors) after one second, the emulator turns into a black screen.

```
String str="";
InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.readme);
StringBuilder finalstring=new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
try {
   while(str!=bf.readLine()){
      finalstring.append(str);
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}

TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvli);
tv.setText(finalstring);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `while` statement with this:

```
while((str = bf.readLine()) != null) {
   finalString.append(str);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your while loop appears to be the problem. The condition in it doesn't really make sense. Try:

```
while((str = bf.readLine()) != null){
    finalstring.append(str);
}
```

Your current loop will never run, as it will evaluate to "while str doesn't equal the line form my text file"